# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x995ee8b0 in tid 29853 (Finalizer)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy haciendo una app, que me manda este error, estuve buscando el error en internet y encontré que probablemente mi error se genera porque tendo un método que está enviando cambios en el enlace de datos sin enviar el hilo de la interfaz de usuario , encontré que puedo solicionar este problema a través de la implementación de **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** / **UI thread**. Pero desconosco completamente como implementarlo a mi aproyecto o en todo caso a el metodo sobre el que estoy trabajando.

Este es el error que estoy recibiendo.

> No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
>
> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
>   07-10 16:38:07.878 E/mono-rt ( 1929): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
>   07-10 16:38:07.878 E/mono-rt ( 1929): used by your application.
>
> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x69432220 in tid 1959 (Finalizer)

No pongo mi código porque me temo que la clase que se ejecuta el error es muy larga, pero si alguien puediese ayudarme o guiarme un poco estaría genial. 
Quisiera saber si alguien puede darme un ejemplo de como usar  **Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread** , o alguna refrencia.
Gracias a todos

Comment: _La clase que se ejecuta el error es muy larga_, pero la línea de código donde ocurre el problema no. ¿No hay Logcats, resultados de debug? ¿Algo que te ayude a encontrar el problema de acceso a memoria no perteneciente a tu aplicación?

Comment: pues eso que subí es lo que me dice el debug, y las lineas entre donde entrar el error y este punto, qué es lo ultimo que tira, son demasiadas para una respuesta de Stack.